# Variable from JavaScript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Here is the code:

```
    $('#sousmenu a').click (function (){
        startSlideshow(<?php echo json_encode(glob("photos-" .$_GET["folder"]. "/*.jpg"));?>);
        return false;
    });
```

The question is I like the HREF to change and get caught by PHP, now it doesn't do anything, but writing the `?folder=portraits` works.

[Here is the page](http://www.studioteknik.com/html2/photo-portfolio.php).

**** Simpler *****
Maybe I am not clear, it happens sometimes!

I want the link href to be send to this PHP function,

```
<?php echo json_encode(glob("photos-" .(i what the href link). "/*.jpg"));?>
```

so clicking on the link `animaux` will send `animaux` to the `glob()` PHP function and will get all the .jpg files in the `photos-animaux` folder.

Clicking on the portraits will send the photo-portraits, etc.

Comment: Yep!, The problem is i capture the click on a html link (href) and do something with the post var in php. the problem is i cannot force the addres bar to change when captured !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the URL and have the added/changed variable picked by PHP interpreter you have to reload your page. Just altering the URL doesn't do anything because JS is executed after PHP processing.

If your site is on `http://example.com` and you wish a `myparam` with value `test` to be passed to PHP you should add something like this in your JS:

```
document.location = 'http://example.com?myparam=test';
```

This will reload your page adding a new param which can be accessed in PHP by simply using `$_GET['myparam']` variable.

You may also want to consider using AJAX to dynamically changing the contents of your page without having to refresh the whole page, but that's a little bit more complicated.

Comment: tell me how to do it in AJAX, that is the way to go (i think). now the only way i used ajax, is with the $("$somediv").load("somefile.txt") to load the content of somefile in somediv

Comment: Here's the nice tutorial on how to use PHP and jQuery for simple AJAX calls: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/ajax-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source in your browser.

Php is server-side, and that means you need to use ajax or reload whole page to get a response.

There is a nice ajax part of tutorial on jquery website, after reading it you should be able to do what you want: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Rate_me:_Using_Ajax